# JavaScript design patterns: Injecting a dependency that is not yet created

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dependency-injection, commonjs

I have a CommonJS module:

```
// main-module
module.exports = function () {
  var foo,
      someModule = require('other-module')(foo);

  // A value is given to foo after other-module has been initialised
  foo = "bar";
}
```

As you can see, this requires `other-module`:

```
// other-module.js
module.exports = function (foo) {
  function example() {
    console.log(foo);
    // > "bar"
  }
}
```

I would like the `example` function inside of `other-module` to be aware of the `foo` variable inside of `main-module`, even though is it established after the module is required.

When `other-module` runs, `foo` will not be `undefined`. However, the point is that by time my `example` function runs, `foo` will have been given a value of `bar`.

The pattern above obviously does not work. What design pattern do I need to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super-familiar with CommonJS, so this might not be the idiomatic way to do it, but using a function instead of a variable should work:

```
// main-module
module.exports = function () {
  var foo,
      someModule = require('other-module')(function() { return foo; });

  foo = "bar";
}

// other-module.js
module.exports = function (fooFn) {
  function example() {
    console.log(fooFn());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The foo value (a string) will be passed by value, so it's `undefined` inside other-module. You could use an options object that is passed by reference:

```
var options = {},
someModule = require('other-module')(options);

options.foo = "bar";
```

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh change `options = {"foo": "bar"};` to `options.foo = 'bar';` and it will.

Comment: Thanks @MattBall, you're right. If we assign a new value to options we have the same problem as when we passed the string by value - so we need to keep the `options` reference the same.